# How to turn off the inspector by default when opening Chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, web-inspector

I"m constantly opening new Chrome Dev tools instances, and the default 'inspector mode' highlighting of DOM elements is really annoying.  I'd like to have it off by default (but still available if I click on the cursor).

Is there a chrome setting to disable this?